# What is the order of operations for compound boolean expressions in an "if" statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, boolean-expression

If i have an if statement

```
if (var1 || var2 && var3)
{
    //anything
}
```

What is the order it evaluates these variables?

I guess really what I would like to know is if this if statement would be equivalent to

```
if ((var1 || var2) && var3){}
//or
if (var1 || (var2 && var3)){}
```

and does order matter in the first instance

I understand I could clarify this with brackets and it would evaluate them in an order I expect. But I was wondering the default way they are viewed when no brackets are present.

Comment: Check out [Operator precedence and associativity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Kind of hard to find because of how much info there is on || and &&.

Comment: You can think of it in terms of arithmetic - `or` is `+`; `and` is `*`. In that case, `var1 || var2 && var3` maps to `var1 + var2 * var3` which is `var1 + (var2 + var3)`. Mapping back to Boolean algebra, you have `var1 || (var2 && var3)`. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx), `&&` has precedence over `||`. After precedence is established, then it flows from left to right. So, in your example, it ends up being if `(var1 || (var2 && var3)){}`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think this is the right answer, but all the answers that have come and gone really speaks wonders to being specific because this will bite you in the butt.

Comment: yeah no kidding. I think this is one of those things that you never have to worry about, until you do.